# How to specify a shielded VM and secure boot for a dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

The [dataflow job run](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run) command has several parameters for workers such as `worker-machine-type`. But I don't see a specification for Shielded VM and Secure Boot. Is there a way to designate these parameters to the dataflow job?
The issue is that the ["Shielded VM" policy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints) has been set at the organization level so the job fails with

```
Startup of the worker pool in zone us-west1-a failed to bring up any of the desired 2 workers. The project quota may have been exceeded or access control policies may be preventing the operation; review the Stackdriver Logging \"GCE VM Instance\" log for diagnostics
```

Answer (score 2):

At this time, it is not possible to specify Dataflow job parameters to meet your organization constraint.

There is a Issue Tracker for this item:

[Support Shielded VMs for the Underlying GCE Instances](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156442870)

I recommend adding yourself to this issue to increase visibility.

**[UPDATE 2022-07-07]**

Credit to @martin-beck's post providing updated status.

[Dataflow Shielded VM](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-shielded-vm)

> Starting on June 1, 2022, the Dataflow service uses Shielded VM for
> all workers. To learn more about Shielded VM capabilities, see
> [Shielded VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/shielded-vm).

Comment: No more in my side. I had a look to the source code, and you haven't option for shielded VM and confidential computing. I also found nothing in the [Apache Beam Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM). You can create an entry there if you want. *Side remark: I always test the organization policies in a side GCP organisation to evaluate this kind of impacts.*

Answer (score 2):

Dataflow now supports using Shielded VMs.  Their use is enabled by specifying a runtime parameter.

```
--dataflowServiceOptions=enable_secure_boot
```

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-shielded-vm

Comment: This works correctly from the command line. However, gCloud CLI still doesn't support this flag. To pass this as a parameter in UI or through CLI we specify flag named `--additional-experiments=enable_secure_boot` which solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following up since I've seen this come up myself. As of June 1, 2022 the Dataflow Service always uses Shielded VMs now. It doesn't need to be explicitly mentioned anymore.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-shielded-vm